# Import class from parent package in Java

Tags: java

I suspect I misunderstood some basic concept of packages in Java.
Here is my hierarchy of the project:

- Application (class with main)
- ***Option*** (class)
- Algorithm (Package)

  - ***PreProcessOptions*** (class)
  - GenerateImage (class)

Now, I would like that ***PreProcessOptions*** class will use ***Option*** class, to get all necessary data, but my IDE cannot find the class.

Any explanations? 
Thanks.

Comment: In which package Option class is?

Comment: Is your Option class in the main package ?

Comment: Wich access modifier does your Option class have?

Comment: Although their naming seems to be hierarchical, packages in Java are not hierarchical in any way inside the language/JVM, although your real problem is using the default package.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a structure like this.

```
src
 -> main
     -> Application (class with main)
     -> Option (class)
 -> Algorithm (Package)
     -> PreProcessOptions (class)
     -> GenerateImage (class)
```

Now in your PreProcessOption class import the main package.

```
package Algorithm;
import main.Option;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! that's helped.
I created a new package called Application, and dragged Application.class and Options.class to that package.
From there, I could access Options from PreProcessOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method. There are two levels of access control:

- At the top level—public, or package-private (no explicit modifier).
- At the member level—public, private, protected, or package-private (no explicit modifier).

A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)